# Sql string interpolation with slick 2.1 with more than 22 parameters

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

I'm using string interpolation with slick for generating sql request.

Slick string interpolation is working fine when I have less than 22 parameters.

Example:

```
val s = sql"select * from my_table where my_table.id = $i"
```

But as slick is using tuples and auto-tupling, I cannot write queries with more than 23 parameters.

Example:

```
val s = sql"""select * from my_table 
              where a1 = $i1 and a2 = $i2 and .... and a23 = $i23"""
```

For the moment the only solution I've found it's to create a new custom string interpolation for each query with more than 23 parameters.

Example:

```
  case class A(q1: Q1, q2: q2, ..., qn: Qn)

  implicit class CustomSQLInterpolation(val s: StringContext) extends AnyVal {
    /** Build a SQLInterpolationResult via string interpolation */
    def csql[P](q1: Q1, q2: Q2, ..., qn: Qn) = {
      val a = A(q1, q2, ..., qn)
      val setTupleA = new SetTupleParameter[A](
        SetQ1, SetQ2, ..., SetQ3)

      new SQLInterpolationResult[A](s.parts, a, setTupleA)
    }
  }
```

But this approach is not generic and not really convenient to use.

Comment: This might be a limitation of Scala. For functions, I know that the language only has defined up to Function22.

Comment: @redeagle47 In scala 2.11 fonctions and case classes are not limited to 22 arguments but tuples are.

Comment: Ah, good to know, I didn't know they changed that.